# validating local storage item with any boolean comparison action crash only in chrome and android device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cordova, cross-platform, local-storage

im writing an app using phonegap and knockout. i wanted the function which access my local storage to return empty string instead of null value for nonexisting keys. from some reason, it works fine on firefox and safari, but crashes when i try to use it in chrome or, tragically, my android device.
it looks like that:

```
function get(key) {
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("" + key);
if(value)return value;
return "";
```

when returning the value variable without any logic(return value;) it works. i've tried using typeof(value)==="string", value!==null, and some trenaries, all with the exact same result.i even tried

```
function isNull(value){
    try{
        if(value==null) return true;
        return false;
    }
    catch(e){
        return true;
    }
}
function get(key){
    var value = window.localStorage.getItem("" + key);
    if(isNull(value)) return "";
    return value;
}
```

with the same result, the program crashes.
help anyone?

update: eventually this worked:

```
function get(key) {
    var value=load(key);
    if(!value) return "";
    return value;
    }
function load(key){
    var value = window.localStorage.getItem("" + key);
//  if(value == null)
//  value = "";
    return value;

}
```

i am sick and tired of all this webkit bullshit i have to keep putting up with. why does google hate us?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just check your value

```
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("" + key);
if(value == null)
value = "";
return value
```

Comment: as i said, i tried that. actually i said i tried value!==null but its pretty much the same thing, and even so iv'e checked them both, no good.